# Find the maximum possible area of a right triangle?

Tags: geometry

What's the largest possible area for a right triangle whose hypotenuse is $5$ cm long?

How to do this by geometry not by calculus?

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
Take the hypotenuse as the diameter of a circle, let the right angle vertex move along the circle and keep in mind that the area is half the hypotenuse times the height dropped onto it.

Comment: I like the part that finds the maximum area based on the altitude only and the approach in calculus is totally avoided.

Comment: m not getting this  area is half the hypotenuse times the height dropped onto it.

Comment: @sana Recall the most basic area formula for triangles.